# java matcher regexp for floating points and operators wrong?

Tags: java, regex

I want to try to filter all operators and operands including floating points 
from a commandline input with regexp. the operators work fine and the floating point works when i use it with a seperate matcher but i want to solve this in one regexp term
my code till now does

```
    Matcher numbers = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+").matcher(expr);
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[\\+|\\*|/|\\-|\\^|\\!|_|([0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+)]").matcher(expr);

    while(numbers.find()) {
            System.out.print(" " + numbers.group() + " num \n"); 
    }

    while (m.find()) {
       System.out.print(" " + m.group() + " -- \n");
    }
```

heres the output

3.0 num 
 2 num

3 -- 
 . -- 
 0 -- 
 2 --

as you see the numbers matcher just finds floating points and normal numbers and that works fine. but if i use it in the second matcher devided by an `or`
i get 3 . 0 as separate matches.

Comment: sry my expr was:   3.0 2 +         polish notation calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC Java regexes use parentheses for a grouping operator, not square brackets like you've got there. Have you tried

```
"(\\+|\\*|/|\\-|\\^|\\!|_|([0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+))"
```

instead? Because what you've got is just a large, multiply redundant character set: It should merely match any one of the characters between the first left square bracket and the final right square bracket. That seems to be the behavior you're seeing.

Or did I completely misunderstand the intent of the second regex?

Comment: ok the square brackets where indeed the problem, i can leave them out as suggested or set round brackets around the whole thing, this works both. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the [] around the whole thing. Those make it into a nested character class (something that's specific to Java regular expressions), so you're just looking for single characters in the list `\|+*/-^!_(0123456789].?)` when all the duplicates are eliminated.